# String vs StringWriter to handle a big String

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications, freemarker

I have to handle a big string in my project, it's the html of a simple page.

To do that I have two possibilities: Either use `String` class or use `StringWriter`. I would like to know what is the best in performance and in memory usage.

What are the differences and what do you suggest?

Comment: If you're going to use String, consider the fact it's immutable if you want to edit the content.

Comment: `StringWriter` is basically an Adapter that adapts a `StringBuffer` to the Writer interface.

Comment: I read this html from the DB or a file

Comment: Are you altering it before serving it?  How big is it?  What concurrency do you expect to need to support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the choice is between [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) and [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html), not `StringWriter`.

[`StringWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StringWriter.html) is a character output stream and I suppose is not what you need.

String is an immutable type, so once created its value can't be modified. StringBuffer is more useful when you need to do many manipulations on the characters sequence.

So if you need, for example, to concatenate a large amount of strings, then I'll go for `StringBuffer`.

[Here](http://blog.vogella.com/2009/07/19/java-string-performanc/) you find an interesting post about this. Take a look.

Answer (score 1):

String is immutable, so if your string has to be built in a way or if it changes a lot - String is no good.
I recommend `StringBuilder`.

Comment: I don't need to change before use, but i need faster class to pass it to freemarker

Answer (score 1):

`String` is an immutable class, it can't be changed. `StringBuilder` is a mutable class that can be appended to, characters replaced or removed and ultimately converted to a `String`.

`StringWriter` is basically an Adapter that adapts a `StringBuffer` to the Writer interface.

Note that if you are using Java 5 or newer, you should use `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer`. From the API documentation:

> As of release JDK 5, this class has been supplemented with an equivalent class designed for use by a single thread, `StringBuilder`. The `StringBuilder` class should generally be used in preference to this one, as it supports all of the same operations but it is faster, as it performs no synchronization.

For [More](http://kaioa.com/node/59)

Answer (score 0):

If length of your text is really long you should use `StringBuilder`